# Oversampling in Longitudinal/Panel Data

Tags: panel-data, unbalanced-classes, oversampling, smote

Would make sense to apply any oversampling (e.g. SMOTE et similia) techniques in order to balance the outcome classes in the context of longitudinal/panel data? Wouldn't such procedures ignore the correlation amongst observations (e.g. in a classic design of a patient observed for 2 or more time points) might just introduce more noise in the analysis synthesizing new observations at random time points-wise?

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Statisticians do not see class imbalance as such a problem, and there is no need to use artificial balancing to solve a non-problem. It might be helpful if you say why you find the imbalance problematic. 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: Related to Dave's excellent comment you have fallen into a very common machine learning trap of wrongly conceptualizing a sensible analyses of _tendencies_ to get a disease (probability of disease) as a forced-choice premature decision classification problem.  Medical diagnosis and prognosis are areas for which classification is singularly unhelpful, and tendencies are everything.